# How to redirect to other views after file download using backbone js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using backbone js and atmosphere js in my application.
I have two tabs on my view as `Delete` and `Download`. I am able to download file using following code:

```
var link = "/myEndPointURL?download?id=1234";
$downloadButton.off("click").on("click", function(e){
    window.location.href = link;

});
```

This code downloads file but after downloads the file but after download, when I clicks on `delete` tab,  I am not able to push that view . It gives me error as "No suspended connection available .....".

Am I using correct approach or do I use any other way. 
I do not want to reload page.

Can someone help me to solve above issue?

Comment: Can you include the code for the click event on the Delete tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download links in single-page apps **could simply be** a link that opens in another tab or window using **`target="_blank"`**.

```html
<a href="/myEndPointURL?download?id=1234" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

That way, you let the browser handle clicking on a link rather than doing it with `window.location.href`. It also lets the app at the state it was without reloading.

Comment: It opens new tab and closes it after download complete in chrome but in firefox the tab remains open. can I close it on completion of download?

Comment: @Vishwas that's a browser or a user preference that should be out of scope for your application.